# Python: Time periods into 'shift' buckets

Tags: python, date-range

I have a data set that contains "sign in" and "sign out" times for users. I want to look at the full time range and say how much of the time fell into shift 1 (5:30-1:30), shift 2 (1:30-9:30) and shift 3 (9:30-5:30). Can this be done?

Within this data set, there can be one person signed into multiple stations during overlapping times. I don't want to add those times together, so I'm currently just taking the min sign in and max sign out times and doing a datediff. The issue is, their shift is considered only by the sign in time. So, if a person comes in 2 minutes before their shift at 1:28, it puts their hours in shift 1 when it should be shift 2... Any ideas on how to handle this?

Comment: Welcome, please add some code in order to attract more viewers

Comment: Sure this can be done, but SO isn't really a place to get general help or guidance. You'll have better luck if you start coding and come here for help with more specific programming problems.

Comment: see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 0):

This is a basic answer to get you going. You want the time divided over three shifts. So the working hours have to be split up into three buckets. The bucket boundaries are defined by the start and end times of the shifts. For the sake of the example I have hardcoded today's date. You'll obviously need to adjust that.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

shift_start=(datetime(2018,3,5,5,30),
             datetime(2018,3,5,13,30),
             datetime(2018,3,5,21,30))
shift_end=  (shift_start[1],
             shift_start[2],
             shift_start[0] + timedelta(days=1))
```

Next, you have a sign-in time and a sign-out time. I have put your hyphothetical user working across three shifts, which would be illegal where I live, but it allows for quicker demonstration.

```
start_time = datetime(2018,3,5,5,45)
end_time = datetime(2018,3,5,21,45)
```

Now you need a function that tells you, for any given pair of sign-in and sign-out times, how much time falls into each shift:

```
def time_in_shift(start, end, shift_start, shift_end):
    if start < shift_start:
        start = shift_start
    if end > shift_end:
        end = shift_end
    return end-start
```

Use this to split the time into three buckets:

```
for shift in range(3):
    print ("Time in shift", shift, time_in_shift(start_time, end_time, shift_start[shift], shift_end[shift]))

Time in shift 0 7:45:00
Time in shift 1 8:00:00
Time in shift 2 0:15:00
```

This needs some polishing to cover corner cases. For example, if someone signs in at 05h15, then they have been signed in for 15 minutes of the last shift of the *previous* day. Depending on the intent of your application, then that time might equally well be assigned to the last shift of the *current* day; or not. So that's up to you to resolve. If your intent is to calculate wages then you will also need to take weekends into account, because typically people get paid more for working weekends. And you will also need to know when the weekend starts. Is it 21h30 on Friday or 00h00 on Saturday? If the latter then you actually have 4 shifts not 3: 21h30 to 23h59 and 00h00 to 05h30.